# Problem if the node_modules wasn't already created in the project directory while using docker-compose and volumes

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, node-modules, volume

I am struggling with a problem where the node modules' folder should be created before running the docker otherwise, I am getting vite not found.

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  node:
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: ./docker/node/Dockerfile
    container_name: node
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - node_modules:/srv/app/node_modules
volumes:
  node_modules:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: "none"
      o: "bind"
      device: "../node_modules"
```

My node `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /srv/app

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json to the working directory
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

# Copy the rest of the application files
COPY . .


EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

My project structure is:

```
|-- docker/
|   |-- node/
|       |-- Dockerfile
|   |-- docker-compose.yml
|-- package.json
|-- package-lock.json
|-- other vue js project structure
```

The error I am getting is

```
ERROR: for node  Cannot create container for service node: failed to mount local volume: mount /home/mohammad/Desktop/Vuejs/vite-project/node_modules:/var/lib/docker/volumes/docker_node_modules/_data, flags: 0x1000: no such file or directory
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

However, If I created the folder **node_modules** by hand in the host, It's working perfectly. Could someone please tell me what is the problem?

Comment: You're overwriting your image's `node_volumes` directory with the named volume.  This isn't necessary, and can cause problems like ignoring changes in the `package.json` file.  Delete all of the `volumes:` blocks, and use the `node_modules` tree that's built into the image.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thank you for your comment. Could you please elaborate what you mean by your suggestion? I am still new to docker. Also, I have tried to map the project folder using the volumes, and it seems to work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by changing the `docker-compose.yml` file volume and redirect it to the whole project.

The updated file is :

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  node:
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: ./docker/node/Dockerfile
    container_name: node
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - app:/srv/app
volumes:
  app:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: "none"
      o: "bind"
      device: ".."
```